# Background view modifier does not create a new instance of its view when the parent view reloads

Tags: swift, swiftui

#### Problem

In SwiftUI, I use a `ForEach` that loads a few that uses the `background` view modifier. When the `ForEach` loop reloads because the model changes, then the view gets updated. But the instance that is created in the `background` view modifier is reused. Why?

#### Details

Given the following view

```
struct PathView: some View {
  let path: URL

  init(path: URL) { // <-- 1
    self.path = path
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ...
    }
    .background(SubDirView(of: path)) // <-- 2
  }
}
```

I have a `ForEach` in some other view that loads this `PathView` view 8 times.

```
ForEach(0...7, id: \.self) { index in
  PathView(path: paths[index])
}
```

The `paths` array might change so that the `ForEach` loop has to load 8 new `PathView` views. This works as expected. Using the debugger, I can see that 8 times the constructor of `PathView` is called (see `// <-- 1`). But there is no new instance of `SubDirView` created and applied to the `background` view modifier (see `// <-- 2`). This leads to the issue that the wrong `path` is used for the views. It seems like that the instance of `SubDirView` is being cached and then reused when the view is created newly.

My expectation would be that if a new instance of `PathView` is created, then there is also a new instance of `SubDirView` created that is attached to the `background` view modifier.

#### Actual Question

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Is this expected by SwiftUI? Is this something related to the Swift language?

(I'm using Swift 5.7 on macOS 12.6 with the latest greatest XCode updates)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. I cannot reproduce. Please show things including but not limited to: what is `SubDirView`? How is the `paths` array changed? What is in the `...` part?

Comment: You shouldn't be using indices with `ForEach` -- that leads to this type of behavior. Instead, use `Identifiable` data